# how can I pass from DCG in Horn clauses with function \+

Tags: prolog, dcg

I want to translate a  grammar rule like this, into a clause

```
char(C) --> [C], { code_type(C, graph), \+ memberchk(C, "()") }.
```

but does not work

```
char(C,In,Out):-
   In=[C|Out],
   code_type(C, graph), 
   \+ memberchk(C, "()").
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `expand_term/2` built-in Prolog predicate to expand grammar rule into clauses:

```
?- expand_term((char(C) --> [C], { code_type(C, graph), \+ memberchk(C, "()") }), Clause).
Clause = (char(C, [C|_G1665], _G1651):- (code_type(C, graph), \+memberchk(C, [40, 41])), _G1651=_G1665).
```

Comment: thank you very much Paulo. I found a new love (expand_term) :)